# Which is the best way to define the value of data being added to my database?

Tags: mysql, database

For example, I have a column > shopping_cart.status; and this column status should for each record contain one of three values > "incomplete" "complete" or "shipped".  My question is, should it be my application that makes sure that these are the only values used, or do i need to build this into the domain of this attribute on the database side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enums thats exactly what they are meant for.

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column
>   specification at table creation time.
>
> An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal; it may not be an
>   expression, even one that evaluates to a string value. For example,
>   you can create a table with an ENUM column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE shoppingcards (
    shoppingcardstatus ENUM('incomplete', 'complete', 'shipped')
);
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: I see. Is it possible to for my enum list to be generated from a another table so I don't have to go in a update the table directly. So i'd be able to add my options to a table and expand the valid data acceptable.